# FullCalendar - Date Sorting Multiple Event Sources in a Custom View

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am working on a project utilizing FullCalendar that has [multiple event sources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources). This is working very well for FullCalendar's default views, however for custom views I am noticing that the dates are not being sorted, and instead I am only getting results in the order of each array. I have created a CodePen to illustrate. Notice that "My View" does not sort properly, but that all of the default views work without issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth timeGridWeek timeGridDay MyView"
    },
    views: {
      MyView: {
        duration: {
          days: 365
        },
        visibleRange: {
          start: '2021-01-01',
          end: '2021-12-31'
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: [CustomViewPlugin_MyView],
    eventSources: [
      calSourceClasses,
      calSourceEvents
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

[Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/mrentropy/pen/xxgqXYb)